# jQuery download HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Tampermonkey to display some additional info about products.

I'm getting information about products from the same website, but requesting them with

```
$.get(url, function(data, response){/*do something*/});
```

sometimes the fetched info it 100% correct, but sometimes it just cuts it short...

Could that be jQuery's character limit?

If it is, how can I download only the part of the HTML I want (that's the window.globalVariable almost at the top of website)?

Could that be a restriction that I haven't taken into account?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery's GET has a character limit, try using POST instead.

GET is limited to 2,048 characters including the other character in the URL. POST has no limit for name/value pairs as they are transferred in the request body and not the URL.

Comment: That makes sense, but the problem is that I'm downloading HTML source from their website, scraping it for info and then displaying info... I can't really use POST for that... If I can, please point me into right direction.

Comment: Wanted to edit, but can't, I've tried it with POST, but I get error 500, because they've blocked POST requests and it shows up as an error.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was my fault, I was cutting data at ";" but if there was ";" in text, the JSON received would be incomplete... I've replaced it with "};"+1 and now it works fine. Thanks for the help :D